# Insert into the front of a MongoDB document array without $position and $each?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

When deploying a meteor app to a sandbox MongoDB that isn't updated to Mongo 3.0 i can't use the `$position` and `$each` queries.

Is there another way to achieve what i am doing with these queries?

I want to add a task to the front of the array.

Here is the code in the method:

```
newTask: function(task, date, number) {

    if (! Meteor.userId()) {
        throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }

    if(number === 0){
        projectsDB.update({user: Meteor.user()._id}, {$push: {'panels.0.tasks': { $each: [{name: task, date: date}], $position: 0}}})
    } else if(number === 1){
        projectsDB.update({user: Meteor.user()._id}, {$push: {'panels.1.tasks': { $each: [{name: task, date: date}], $position: 0}}})
    } else if(number === 2){
        projectsDB.update({user: Meteor.user()._id}, {$push: {'panels.2.tasks': { $each: [{name: task, date: date}], $position: 0}}})
    } else if(number === 3){
        projectsDB.update({user: Meteor.user()._id}, {$push: {'panels.3.tasks': { $each: [{name: task, date: date}], $position: 0}}})
    }
}
```

But essentially how could I recreate

```
projectsDB.update({user: Meteor.user()._id}, {$push: {'panels.3.tasks': { $each: [{name: task, date: date}], $position: 0}}})
```

without use `$position` and `$each`?

Comment: how do I create a project? I'm in the dashboard route

Comment: You will need to sign up then once at the dashboard click on "create new"

Comment: oh ok... for some reason that block does not show when you are on a small screen. I think you have to use `check()` for your three parameters there, but first can you paste in the Errors on the server by doing `meteor logs panls.meteor.com`?

Comment: Hi, i have added the logs to the question, also yeah it isn't responsive yet so sorry for about the confusion! Will read into check() now

Comment: While it's always good to use `check()` your errors come from the MondoDB version which is stuck to a prior 2.6 version in Meteor and does not support `$position` in an `$each`

Comment: Hmm i thought that might be the case, i am using a sandbox db on compose as well, will that not 3.0 yet either? Any idea on how i create the same effect without using $position? Thanks for your help

Comment: Will try and look into that but make sure you edit the question now and most importantly add tags like `mongodb` so more people can see it.

Comment: No need, just read about the sandboxes and they aren't kept up to date so that will be the case. Will update now!

Comment: @RaduChiriac Whilst I do not "generally" aggree with posting things like "meteor" questions to a MongoDB tag as suggested, that "general" position is because the questions tend to be "meteor API specific" and therefore do not have a place with extended tagging. However, I do believe this **was** such a case, as more generalized tags here do actually expose this to solutions that are **not** meteor specific at all. It should depend on what the question is actually asking, and in this case there are indeed general "JavaScript" and also "MongoDB" specific cases that can be applied. So good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually thought this was quite simple really, and commented but then thought about it and it's really an answer.

It depends on which case actually suits but there are two alternates here.

1. Just continue adding items to the array with a standard [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operation. This just "appends" ( rather than pre-pend ) to the the array always anyhow.

   ```js
   projectsDB.update(
       { user: Meteor.user()._id }, 
       { $push: {
           'panels.0.tasks': { name: task, date: date }
       }}
   )
   ```

   So no worries about supported modifiers there, as all new entries just go to the back rather than the front.

   But when you read the data back then all you need to do is apply JavaScript [`.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to the array. The construct is simple, just either put it in a helper or within something to "publish" as required:

   ```js
   var projects = projectsDB.find(query).fetch();
   projects.forEach(function(project) {
       project.panels.forEach(function(panel) {
           panel.tasks.reverse();   // reverses the order
       });
   })
   ```

   You just need to be aware if you "publish" like that to pre-process the `.reverse()` again before appending anything else. So probably better suited to a display helper only.
2. Since I see a "date" in there, it would seem logical that you want the "newest task" to be the first listed. So all you really need to do here is apply the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) modifier which is already supported:

   ```js
   projectsDB.update(
       { user: Meteor.user()._id }, 
       { $push: 
           { 'panels.0.tasks': { 
               $each: [{name: task, date: date}], 
               $sort: { date: -1 }
           }}
       }
   )
   ```

   Then the "newest" entry will always be at the "front" as the list is "sorted" by the date property on every update. Not sure if the meteor version or the MongoDB version you have supports `$sort` without a [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifier as well. If required just either set that to your required maximum size or a number larger than the maximum expected entries so it does not have an effect in the latter case.

The [`$position`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) modifier itself was intended for much wider usage than simply "pre-pending" to an array, so there have always been other ways to achieve the same thing, before it's introduction.

As of writing I believe this is yet to make it into "minimongo" anyway, so regarless of the server version, any client side code would not be able to use the operator. But the two above choices certainly will work client side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the information, i ended up actually just using a full deployment which has $position ready for use as I have multiple web apps that needed db hosting, but the first method would do the job! I had already tried the second one but unfortunately that didn't work but that is due to me using moment().format so its not actually a date so i could use a createdAt and new Date() to fix that, the date i am using is more an aesthetic for the user. Its all up an running at http://panls.io  now thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

From your past question edits, this is what the server prompted: `MongoError: $each term takes only $slice (and optionally $sort) as complements`.

Remove `$position` as it has only been introduced in MongoDB 2.6 and try this hack using negative indexes:

```
{
  $set: {
     'panels.0.tasks.-1': {name: task, date: date}
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have added "projectsDB.update({user: Meteor.user()._id}, {$push: {'panels.0.tasks': {$each: [{name: task, date: date}], $sort: {date: -1}}}})" and it doesn't have the desired affect, when i add new tasks it appears the in original order, newest at the bottom, any idea?

Comment: I updated my answer. Try and use a negative index in a $set. I am out of ideas for the moment.

Comment: Also, add a template "loading" to get rid of that other error.